# Can you backup cached memory of an open file using Shadow Copy (VSS)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, shadow-copy

If I wanted to create a backup of a MS Word document that was open, I would need to close the file before any backup was possible. With Shadow Copy, I can backup an open file, but would the unsaved changes be backed up with the snapshot of the Word document?

I am trying to create a program that automatically creates backups of file(s) using Shadow Copy (VSS). I already have the Windows Task Scheduler setup but need the batch file for execution. However, I cannot seem to understand how to create such a batch file so that I can create a backup of an open file by Shadow Copying it onto another drive.

This is for personal/basic use. I cannot grasp how to backup the unsaved information that would be "cached" in an open MS Word document. Is this even possible?

Comment: Shadow copy is meant for large database programs. It sends the program a message to make it's files on disk consistent and don't write to them until I finish backing up. Word doesn't touch your files until you save. It has an amazingly large amount of temp files, incl autosave. It also has an open temp file that if you save will become the new main file. Word saves to temp file, deletes old file, renames temp file to old file.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mssmallbiz/2012/04/20/how-to-recover-that-un-saved-microsoft-office-excel-word-or-powerpoint-file-you-closed-before-saving/ and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316951/how-to-recover-a-lost-word-document and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files

Comment: Sorry, my post wasn’t worded accurately. The Word Document was an example of a file. I was trying to refer to those types of documents, such as txt files or maybe an image in the middle of editing it. Would Shadow Copy be able to backup open files like those?

Comment: If the program supports it OR if the program opened it in a way that it doesn't matter.